# Issue with ng-init and ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some issues with initializing a global variable to use in all the functions on mycontroller :

Here is what I've done so far:

**JS** :

```
$scope.init = function (table) {
    alert("alert 1 : " + table);
    $scope.tableName = table;
    alert($scope.tableName);
};

tableName = $scope.tableName;
alert("alert 2 : " + tableName);
```

**HTML** :

```
<div ng-init="init('RIGHTTABLE')" ng-controller="DropdownCaptionCtrl">
```

I have the alerts on my browser with this order:

> alert 2 : undefined
>
> alert 1 : RIGHTTABLE

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue ?

What I want is to have the alerts at this order :

> alert 1 : RIGHTTABLE
>
> alert 2 : RIGHTTABLE

**In fact I want to have a global variable `$scope.tableName` to be used in all my controllers functions, I want to initialize it at the launch of the page**

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaKWd?editors=101)

Thank you

Comment: tableName = $scope.tableName; ? whats this code ? could you please explain

Comment: ng-init is called after the controller is loaded. So for sure 'allert 2' will be called first.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll make a snippet

Comment: @shushanthp look the plunker : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaKWd?editors=101

Comment: @AntiHeadshot look the plunker : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaKWd?editors=101

Comment: @aBennouna again, because ng-init is called **after** the controller is initialized.

Comment: Yes @AntiHeadshot I know that, is there any solution to solve tjis issue?

Comment: @aBennouna Sajeetharans answer should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your init function get called after geting the variable as undefined since controller is loaded initially, what you can do is

```
$scope.init = function (table) {
    alert("alert 1 : " + table);
    $scope.tableName = table;
    alert($scope.tableName);        
    alert("alert 2 : " + $scope.tableName);
};
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to make use of the variable in all controllers then go for [`Service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Other option is use $rootScope,

```
   $scope.init = function (table) {
        alert("alert 1 : " + table);
        $rootScope.tableName = table;
        alert($rootScope.tableName);        
        alert("alert 2 : " + $rootScope.tableName);
    };
```

Then you will be able to access in any controller using `$rootScope.tableName`

Comment: It's not as simple as alerts, I didn't explain so much.. I want to make a variable `$scope.tableName` usable in all the controller functions

Comment: I want to use the variable in the same controller but in all the functions.. I've tried rootscope but it doesn't work @sajeetharan

Comment: it should work if you are refering in the same controller, create a plunker i will fix

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I'll do it now

Comment: As i explained earlier, ng-init gets called once the controller is read, so when the controller is read initially  the var1 is undefined

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. My question is how to initialize it in order to be used in all the functions in the controller ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94195/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-abennouna).